# Out of memory que es ? android studio

Tags: android

me aparecio esto hoy en mi android studio . Que significa y que opcion elijo que no perjudique mi proyecto ?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Significa que el proceso se quedó sin memoria. Estabas corriendo algo cuando te pasó?

Comment: Abri el android studio , cambie el codigo de la version y el nombre de la version y nada mas.

Comment: Por un lado fijate cual es la configuración de tu maquina en terminos de Memoria / Disco / CPU y si cumple con los requerimientos para Android Studio. Y Por otro lado fijate si estás corriendo procesos pesados que consumen mucha memoria al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Por lo general da cuando se carga ineficientemente un bitmap en la app: Aca podes leer algo de OOM (Out Of Memory)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647057/android-studio-oom-exception

Comment: cuando sale un error similar, ya sea desde el IDE o ejecutando tu aplicación significa que lo que quisiste hacer consumió toda la memoria asignada y llegó al tope. este tope se le asigna a la [JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM156) para que ejecute su Memory Heap, que es donde todos los objetos de tu aplicación viven y mueren a manos del Garbage Collector. y probablemente tomando en cuenta el mensaje del error la sola ejecución del IDE te consume mucha de la memoria asignada y al intentar hacer algo se terminó de consumir.

Comment: Chicos ya lo solucione , cerre el programa , elimine algunas imagenes duplicadas y exceso que tenia en los drawable y mipmap y listo , ya logre crear apk

Comment: @pauuu aunque puede solucionarse "momentáneamente", esto puede surgir nuevamente,te sugiero revises la configuración de tu Android Studio, agregué una respuesta.

Comment: entiendo , muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esto no es problema de consumo de memoria en tu aplicación, en realidad el IDE `Android Studio` no tiene memoria.

Te sugiero aumentar el "Heap size" (`-XmxheapSize`),

> De forma predeterminada, Android Studio tiene un tamaño máximo de
>   de Heap que es 1280 MB. Si trabajas en un proyecto grande o tu sistema
>   tiene mucha RAM, puedes mejorar el rendimiento aumentando el tamaño
>   máximo de montón en las opciones del VM para Android Studio.

esto en el archivo `studio64.exe.vmoptions`, debes reiniciar Android Studio para que realice el cambio.

Pero la mejor opción es realizarlo desde `"Edit Custom VM Options..."`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Es importante comentar que el valor de `-XmxheapSize` debe estar basado en el tamaño de tu proyecto y la memoria RAM disponible en tu equipo.**

Revisa lo que comenta la documentación:

[Como referencia, si tienes más de 4 GB de memoria RAM y un proyecto de tamaño medio, debes fijar el tamaño máximo del montón en 2 GB o más.](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config)

Si deseas fijar el "heap size" en 2 GB puedes usar:

```
-Xmx2g
```